# How to Prevent Docker Container Logs from Disappearing?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

How can I prevent Docker container logs from disappearing when the container crashes, so that I can troubleshoot the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs are deleted when the container is deleted. If you want the logs to persist, then you need to avoid deleting the container. Make sure you aren't running the container with an option like `--rm` that automatically deletes it on exit.

It is also possible to configure logging drivers to delete logs or send them to other locations. For now on that, see https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Comment: yes, I saw these parts, so when I use the log driver, will the logs remain when the container is deleted or crashed? I couldn't find the answer to this.

Comment: @SerkanGün it depends on the log driver. The local and json log drivers store their data as part of the container. Other drivers push to external stores that have their own retention policies (I don't know how you've configured your elastic server).